# 2 divs on sides of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container with some content that is centered on the middle of the page, it looks like this, very simple:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5op11m0j/

I was wondering is it possible, using CSS and :before and :after, to add 2 clickable divs/background images, one on the left side and one of the right side of the container?
I know that the easiest way would be to simply write 2 divs, one before and one after container, but i cant modify the HTML of the snippet i showed because layout is pretty complex

p.s by clickable i meant on background image or div that would be used as ad space

Comment: You can't modify the HTML but you can the CSS, can you modify the JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "clickable"? I don't think it's going to be possible using just css.

Comment: What do you mean by "clickable" divs?

Comment: i can do jquery and javascript (actually, i can modify the html too, but i cant add any more code in this section part because layout is pretty complex)

Comment: it may be easier to just use jQuery instead of css

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to be "clickable" (I'm assuming this means, run a function when it's clicked?) this isn't possible using just css's ::before or ::after function, however it is achievable using jquery.

You may want to use jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/).

```
$( ".container" ).prepend( "<div id=\"firstDiv\">Test</div>" );
```

Then just insert an event for when the user [clicks](https://api.jquery.com/click/) this new div

```
$( "#firstDiv" ).click(function() {
  alert( "div clicked" );
});
```